# need to grab from 2 arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

My arrays:

```
var mexicanFood = ["Taco Bell", "Beans", "Taco Time", "Buritos", "Chalupa"];

var asianFood = ["Noodles", "Rice", "Sushi", "Fish", "Chicken"];

var americanFood = ["Hot dogs", "Pizza", "Burgers", "Nachos", "Other"];
```

Know this is a possibility to grab randomly from array:

```
var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * mexicanFood.length);
```

I want to pull a value from each food category. I don't want all of mexicanFood values to be the result for food options. I want it at random but at least to pull one or two from each category. How can you do that with having it go into radio buttons (maybe 5 radio buttons) and can it be done with Math.random?

Also want it to be in javascript and html if possible

Edit:

I basically want different food categories in arrays. Then have random values pulled from the categories and those values will be put into radio buttons. My overall project that I want to create is a voting poll for restaurants to eat at. So I don't want 5 burger places to come up when I have mexican, asian, american, and other options to randomly pull from.

What I am stuck on is how to randomly pull from each array. I know how to randomly pull from one array list. But when I have mexicanFood, asianFood and americanFood (or even more than those), I am not sure how to randomly pull values from those and have those values populate radio buttons

Comment: Where are you stuck? You know how to create a random index, so if you want 2 random items, generate two random indexes and get their values from the arrays.

Comment: **I want it at random but at least to pull one or two from each category.** Well, now you are straying from what random does.

Comment: Why does this question deserve an up vote?

Comment: I'd suggest combining your arrays and creating objects of the structure `{ name: 'Taco Bell', type: 'mexican' }`. Using the single array makes your life easier and you can still distinguish which foods are of which type.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I want to have different categories that are in the arrays. Then randomly pull from each array. I know how to randomly pull from 1 array but not multiple.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But, the entire point of a random is that it is random. When you add the requirement that it must pull at least one or two, it is no longer a random operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to return an array of random foods, containing at least 1 from each category.

I've created a function called `createRandomArray()`, which accepts an `arraySize`. This `arraySize` refers to the amount of items you wish to have in your final array.

In the function, I'm concatenating all of the food arrays together. I'm then looping through this array to add a random index to a new array.

```js
var mexicanFood = ["Taco Bell", "Beans", "Taco Time", "Buritos", "Chalupa"],
    asianFood = ["Noodles", "Rice", "Sushi", "Fish", "Chicken"],
    americanFood = ["Hot dogs", "Pizza", "Burgers", "Nachos", "Other"];
    
function createRandomArray(arraySize) {
    var allFoods = mexicanFood.concat(asianFood).concat(americanFood),
        randomFoods = [];
    
    if (arraySize <= allFoods.length) {
        randomFoods = [
            mexicanFood[getRandomArrayIndex(mexicanFood)],
            asianFood[getRandomArrayIndex(asianFood)],
            americanFood[getRandomArrayIndex(americanFood)]
        ]; // at at least one from each
        
        // remove the ones that were initially added from each
        allFoods.splice(allFoods.indexOf(randomFoods[0]), 1);
        allFoods.splice(allFoods.indexOf(randomFoods[1]), 1);
        allFoods.splice(allFoods.indexOf(randomFoods[2]), 1);
        
        for (var i = 0; i < arraySize - 3; i++) {
            var randomIndex = getRandomArrayIndex(allFoods);
            
            randomFoods.push(allFoods[randomIndex]);
            allFoods.splice(randomIndex, 1);
        }
        
        return randomFoods;
    }
    
    return allFoods; // requesting more items of food than the amount available, so just add them all
}

function getRandomArrayIndex(array) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
}

var randomFoods = createRandomArray(5);

for (var i = 0; i < randomFoods.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById('food-form').innerHTML += '<input type="radio" name="food" value="' + randomFoods[i] + '"> ' + randomFoods[i] + '<br>';
}
```

```html
<form action="" id="food-form"></form>
```

Comment: Not really clear from the question, but I think there are two constraints: at least one from each, no more than two from each. So only 2:2:1, 2:1:2 and 1:2:2 should work.

Comment: @Okami Is this the case?

Comment: @TobyMellor He also asked that they be put into html radio buttons.

Comment: @TobyMellor I am trying to figure out how to explain it. I basically want different food categories in arrays. Then have random values pulled from the categories and those values will be put into radio buttons. My overall project that I want to create is a voting poll for restaurants to eat at. So I don't want 5 burger places to come up when I have mexican, asian, american, and other options to randomly pull from.

Comment: @Okami Multiple examples of the expected result in the edited question would be helpful

Comment: @TobyMellor your solution is actually really close to what I am wanting. I just want those values to be populated into radio buttons once the values are randomly picked from each array

Comment: @Okami Something like that? Please remember to mark the correct answer :)

Comment: @TobyMellor I have another question for this, is there a way to grab the values from the radio buttons? say it gets populated in the radio button and the options are Noodles, Rice, Taco Bell, Pizza, Burgers. is there a way I can pull those values out and have it print out after hitting a submit button?

Comment: @Okami You should probably make another question for that